# Caesar Cipher in Java - printing blank line

Tags: java, console-application, caesar-cipher

I'm currently trying to write a Caesar Cipher in Java with key 18.

The code I have so far is as follows, but for some reason I cannot work out, it isn't working.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
class MainApplication {
private static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String CryptMessage(int key, String message) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i == message.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(message.charAt(i))) {
            int num = (int) message.charAt(i);
            num = num + key;
            if (Character.isUpperCase(message.charAt(i))) {
                if (num > (int) ('Z')) {
                    num = num - 26;
                } else if (num < (int) ('A')) {
                    num = num + 26;
                }
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(message.charAt(i))) {
                if (num > (int) ('z')) {
                    num = num - 26;
                } else if (num < (int) ('a')) {
                    num = num + 26;
                }
            }
            temp.append((char) num);
        } else {
            temp.append(message.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    message = temp.toString();
    return message;
}
private static void encrypt(){
    int key = 18;
    System.out.println("Please enter a message to encrypt: ");
    String message = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(CryptMessage(key, message));
}
private static void decrypt(){
    int key = -18;
    System.out.println("Please enter a message to decrypt: ");
    String message = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(CryptMessage(key, message));
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Message Encryption System 3.0");
    System.out.println("Please select an option:");
    System.out.println("[1] - Encrypt Message");
    System.out.println("[2] - Decrypt Message");
    String opt = input.nextLine();
    if(Objects.equals(opt, "1")){
        encrypt();
    }
    else if(Objects.equals(opt, "2")){
        decrypt();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    }
}
}
```

The program runs, however, it prints a blank line where the encrypted (or decrypted) message should be.

Comment: did you intend to do this --> `i == message.length();` as your for loop condition? it should be  `i < message.length();`.

Comment: That looks weird to me too

Comment: The issue is that `CryptMessage` is returning an empty string because the for loop condition is not satisfied at all (therefore no statements inside the for loop will be executed) and even if it did, you'd get an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: My mistake, I have corrected that and it works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop condition `i == message.length()` should be `i < message.length()`.

The condition in a `for` loop determines *when to continue to the next iteration*. Your condition is false on the first iteration and the loop terminates immediately (after the first iteration).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that can be solved with a debugger. If you go through your code one line at a time it is easier to catch the fact that the loop conditon nimrodm pointed out doesn't execute the way you expect it to. In addition you can check the values of the variables during execution and make sure they are correct at each step.